# routes in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как в codeigniter в `route` объявить класс

К примеру я делаю вот так

```
class admin extends CI_Controller {
    public function test() {
        echo"helloworld";
    }
}
```

Как мне теперь увидеть страницу по адресу `http://site.ru/admin/test`

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужно вам просто правильно настроить .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Потом в файле config.php нужно настроить

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Comment: Я не совсем про это)) я про роуты, и свои классы.

Comment: К примеру объявил класс, как мне его увидеть в url?

Comment: вы пробовали сделать http://site.ru/index.php/admin/test ? если да, тогда мой ответ вам решит проблему.

Comment: http://localhost/index.php/admin/index открываю, ничего нету.

Comment: Сам класс 
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
 
 public function index() {echo"asd"}}

Comment: для `index` можно `localhost/index.php/admin`

Comment: 1. где расположен класс 2. в какой системе вы работаете? (apache+php или IIS+php)

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29307/discussion-between-saidolim-djuraev-and-).

Comment: апач + пхп. Класс 2 расположен после класса blog в дефолтном контроллере

Comment: вот тут проблема. класс admin должет быть в папке `controllers` и название файла должно быть `admin.php`. В одном файле нельзя быть 2 класса

Answer (score 0):

**aplications/controllers/admin.php** - если так расположен контроллер, то

```
$route['somme_link'] = 'admin/test';
```

если же контроллер расположен в поддериктории, например
**aplications/controllers/admin/admin.php** то соответственно

```
$route['somme_link'] = 'admin/admin/test';
```

somme_link - это соответственно часть ссылки (после домена) по которой переходите
http://site.com/somme_link